# How does one see the specific structure of some variable?

Tags: theming, webforms

I'd normally use `dpm($variableName)`, to drill down to the desired data, but I'm currently working on the `webform-mail.tpl.php` template file, which doesn't exactly allow that.

Most of the Drupal devs I've met seem to have this magical knowledge of how variable structures work, and I want to figure out how they found these things in the first place.

For example, I see people talk about structures like this: `$node->webform['components'][$key]['form_key']` all the time.

How do they find out what's contained inside $node->webform? Is it some functionality in the devel module, or is there an amazing piece of Drupal's documentation that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: xdebug is your best friend. Devel fell short for me years ago. Most IDEs come with support for it out of the box (even VSCode), and modern Drupal tools like Drupal VM or Docker4Drupal include it. All you have to do is wire it up in the editor and set breakpoints everywhere. https://xdebug.org/. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4udxLwRpJ3w

Comment: How would you use xDebug with a template file though? Or would it be necessary to write a short function, then use the debugger to step through that?

Comment: There is a Drupal module called Twig XDebug which adds a twig function `{{ breakpoint() }}` which will trigger xdebug. Honestly, it will change your life. You can add `hook_preprocess_foo` function stubs to your theme file with a breakpoint to inspect `$variables` too. https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you mention Drupal 7. As long as there is a `<?php ` statement in your tpl file, you can set a breakpoint in the IDE and xdebug will stop on the php statement.

Comment: Let me complicate this scenario by saying that I'm editing a particular template by remote, and so I don't actually have an IDE to play with in this case. Generally I work with just Sublime, & the command line. Also, since this is a template that's not attached to a pageload, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around where/how stopping on a statement is going to happen. Am I missing something super-obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a basic-level solution to this one (posting for future php-novices).

PHP has a function called `print_r()` which outputs a human readable version of a variable. If it's a giant array/datastructure like most of the objects in Drupal,

eg:
`print_r($node->webform);` returns:

```
Array
(
[nid] => 7
[confirmation] => 
We'll be getting back to you as soon as we can. We're excited about the 
possibilities and eager to find the solutions you need.

Looking forward to it!

[confirmation_format] => full_html
[redirect_url] => node/29
[status] => 1
...
)
```

and `print_r($submission);` returns:

```
stdClass Object
(
[sid] => 643
[nid] => 7
[uid] => 1
[is_draft] => 0
[submitted] => 1524082096
[remote_addr] => 172.68.142.158
[serial] => 282
...
)
```

It's not as fancy as using a real debugger, but it gives access to what I assumed was off-limits. I suppose I should give PHP more credit sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kint in a template. Enable the devel and kint modules and you can call it right from your template: `{{ kint(node) }}`

Comment: Except `kint` pretty much sucks in most cases because its so large it will cause your browser to crash (Drupal 8), at least it does for me. `xdebug` is a more effective way to debug and step through structures and "see" whats happening.